# mySQL Error 1064: Clarification

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to find all entries whose last modified date is greater that 2015-03-01 and the column of name is null. 
This is the query that I wrote

```
SELECT * FROM `inventory` where date(date_modified) >= date '2015-03-01' AND where name is not null ORDER BY `inventory`.`date_modified`  DESC
```

I get error 1064 when I try running this query.

Comment: `date(date_modified) >= date '2015-03-01'` can be simplified to `date_modified >= '2015-03-01'`

Answer (score 0):

You need parentheses around the argument to `date`. Also, you don't repeat the `WHERE` keyword after `AND`.

```
SELECT * FROM `inventory` 
where date(date_modified) >= date('2015-03-01') 
AND name is not null 
ORDER BY `inventory`.`date_modified`  DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

On your description, you are saying

> the column of name is null

On your query you are saying:

> where name is not null

Which one is the correct?

Your are getting **1064** because your query has a syntax error since your are using `WHERE` twice.

```
SELECT ...WHERE .... AND WHERE
```

This is the way to do it. Please change is null or not null depends what you want

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    inventory
WHERE
    date(date_modified) >= date('2015-03-01') AND name is null -- is not null
ORDER BY inventory.date_modified DESC
```

Comment: I meant the column of name is full. I am sorry for the confusion. I am trying to learn mySQL on the fly.

Comment: No worries. We are all learning. Did you try my option? If you have an issue/error let me know.